# why im not able to see my lightning component in action

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" />
    
        <lightning:card variant="Narrow" title="{!v.contact.Name}" 
                        iconName="standard:contact">
            <aura:set attribute="actions">
                <lightning:button name="details" label="Details" onclick="{!c.goToRecord}" />
            </aura:set>    
            <aura:set attribute="footer">
                <lightning:badge label="{!v.contact.Email}"/>
            </aura:set>
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
                {!v.contact.Phone}
            </p>
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
                {!v.contact.MailingStreet}
            </p>
        </lightning:card>
 
</aura:component>
```

[image: bbb]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your component needs to implement [`force:lightningQuickAction` interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:lightningQuickAction/documentation):

> Add the force:lightningQuickAction interface to a Lightning component
> to allow it to be used as a custom action in Lightning Experience or
> the Salesforce mobile app. You can use these components as
> object-specific or global actions in both Lightning Experience and the
> Salesforce mobile app.

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction">
...
```